# Where does the command line search for executable programs

Tags: linux, path

When I type `git status` or `python foobar.py`, I assume `git` and `python` are executable programs on my computer. Where are these programs stored, and where does the command line search for them? If I have 2 versions of python installed, what version is my computer using when I type `python foobar.py`? I've heard of the `$PATH` environment variable, does `$PATH` store the location of all the executables?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the $PATH variable - default set to locations like (/bin, /sbin, /usr/bin, ...) - will tell your shell where to look for executables. You can change this variable to fit your needs.

For python in particular there should be a python2 and python3 binary in your /usr/bin directory. Most Linux distributions can select a "default" version when multiple slots are installed. In that case there will be a symlink to the correct binary.

You can ask your system with `which python` to see where it is located.

Just as an addendum: If your foobar.py has a shebang (f.e. `#!/usr/bin/python3`) in the beginning you would not need to use `python foobar.py` but instead just call `./foobar.py` and the shebang interpreter would be used.